# Foreign value getting inserted as blank in database. how to resolve this?

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I am trying to insert data in a table where one of the column is foreign key.I have created the association between tables but foreign key is getting inserted as blank.

I have a schema for user_type

```
schema “user_type” do
  field(:type, :string)
  has_many(:roles, Accreditor.Role.Roles, foreign_key: :user_type)

  timestamps()
end

def changeset(user_type, attrs) do
  user_type
  |> cast(attrs, [:type])
  |> validate_required([:type])
  |> unique_constraint(:type)
end
```

and have another one roles schema

```
schema “roles” do
  field(:role_name, :string)
  #field(:user_type, :id)
  has_many(:permissions, Accreditor.Permissions.RolePermissions, 
  foreign_key: :role_id)
  belongs_to(:user_type, UserType)

  timestamps()
end

@doc false
def changeset(roles, attrs) do
  roles
  |> cast(attrs, [:role_name])
  |> validate_required([:role_name])
  |> unique_constraint(:role_name)
end
```

and I am trying to insert data into roles table, the data role_name get inserted, but the foreign key user_type is blank.

kindly help me with this

These are my postgres tables:

```
select * from user_type;
id | type | inserted_at | updated_at
----±------±--------------------±--------------------
 1 | ADMIN | 2019-05-06 09:19:24 | 2019-05-06 09:19:24
```

this is my user_type table

```
select * from roles;
id | role_name | user_type | inserted_at | updated_at
----±----------±----------±--------------------±--------------------
1 | SUPER | | 2019-05-06 09:37:30 | 2019-05-06 09:37:30
```

and this is my roles table where user_type field is empty. Iam not understanding where iam going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You do not do anything to update the `user_type`, why would you expect it to be updated? Use [`Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) to insert an association, somewhat like:

```rb
def changeset(roles, attrs) do
  roles
  |> cast(attrs, [:role_name])
# ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
  |> cast_assoc(:user_type, , with: &UserType.changeset/2)
# ⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑⇑
  |> validate_required([:role_name])
  |> unique_constraint(:role_name)
end
```

Comment: I am not updating user_type..its a foreign key.. and also by using cast_assoc it isnt working. user_type is foreign key column which is referenced with user_type 
    columnERROR 23502 (not_null_violation) null value in column "user_type" 
    violates not-null constraint this is what iam getting that means user_type value is null.

Comment: ```def create_roles(attrs \\ %{}) do
    Ecto.build_assoc(%UserType{}, :roles)
     %Roles{}
    |> Roles.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()```                                                                                              this is my create roles function where user_type column is foreign key

Comment: I am not sure I follow. If FK is mandatory as per DB design, you must set it. If not, remove a constraint from DB.